# Spring Batch: Reading data from one source but writing different data to 2 separate files

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have written a spring batch program to read/process/write data into a single file. I have a new business requirement wherein from the same data what I am reading, I have to build another list with different data and process/format the data and write it onto a separate file.

I have looked into MultiFormatItemWriter in which I can define separate FlatFileItemWriters & CompositeItemWriter as well, but i am unable to understand how to send different lists to these different filewriters.

Please do suggest some options with sample code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [`ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemProcessor.html) and [`ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) is what you are looking for. The classifier allows you to route items to the right processor/writer based on their class.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests.java#L37).